# How can I code a refresh of a HTML.RenderPartial using Ajax in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following view:

```
    @model ViewModels.Shared.BaseViewModel
    <div class="rep_tb0">
        <div class="rep_tr0">
            <div class="rep_td0">@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Link.Position)</div>
            <div class="rep_td0">@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Link.Title)</div> 
        </div>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AdminDetails.Count; i++)
        {
            var qs = "&ac=" + Model.Meta.AccountID +
                     "&me=" + Model.AdminDetails[i].RowKey;  
        <div class="rep_tr0">
            <div class="rep_td0">
                @Html.TextBox(("Position_" + @i), Model.AdminDetails[i].Position, new { size = 2 })
            </div>
            <div class="rep_td0">@Model.AdminDetails[i].Title</div>             
        </div>  
        }
    </div>
```

Populated by this controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Detail(string ac, string me)
    {
            vm.AdminDetails = _link.Detail(ac + me).ToList();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

I would like to use Ajax, jQuery and HTML.Renderpartial as there are times when I need to request a refresh of the data for example when I change the value of position.

I am totally new to the idea of doing this. I found links that help me but mostly it was about Ajax with earlier versions of MVC and not so much about MVC3. Can someone give me some pointers. I am not looking for code. Just a few line example of how I could go about doing the coding in my action method, how I should call the Ajax etc.

Comment: Partials are just a way to modularize portions of a static page, and its concept only exists on the server side. You cannot simply refresh partials using AJAX which is a client-side technology. The partial needs to be available as a static page, and loaded in using AJAX as a separate page. However, a better technique is to simply load in the data you want to refresh (as JSON via an API, for example), and then refresh the data on the page directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a child action, not a partial view.

You can then write

```
<div id="#thingy">@Html.Action("Detail", new { ac, me })</div>

$('#thingy').load("@Server.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("Detail", new { ac, me }))");
```

Comment: Your suggestion looks very interesting. I'm sure you've seen example of what I have in my question. I saw quite a few examples on the internet. How would you compare your way of doing this to my way. I would like to use the way most other people use. Also what would be the return type of the code for Detail on the server need to return?

Comment: The `Detail` action should `return Partial(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea will be that you will use JQuery to fire off an AJAX request when you want your Partial View updated.

The AJAX request will call one of your controller actions, which then will return a PartialViewResult.

The 'success' part of the JQuery AJAX result will get the HTML response, and replace a given container in your View with the new HTML.

e.g.

Your View could look like this:

```
@model ViewModels.Shared.BaseViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#RefreshButton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: *href*,
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function (responseText) {
                    $('#PanelToUpdate').html(responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="PanelToUpdate" class="rep_tb0">
    <div class="rep_tr0">
        <div class="rep_td0">@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Link.Position)</div>
        <div class="rep_td0">@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Link.Title)</div> 
    </div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AdminDetails.Count; i++)
    {
        var qs = "&ac=" + Model.Meta.AccountID +
                    "&me=" + Model.AdminDetails[i].RowKey;  
    <div class="rep_tr0">
        <div class="rep_td0">
            @Html.TextBox(("Position_" + @i), Model.AdminDetails[i].Position, new { size = 2 })
        </div>
        <div class="rep_td0">@Model.AdminDetails[i].Title</div>             
    </div>  
    }
</div>    
<button id="RefreshButton"></button>
```

where *href* is the URL for your controller action.  Aternatively, you could look at an AJAX post method and serialize your form data, if that is needed.

Then, a small tweak to your controller action, so that it can handle being called either via AJAX or normally:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string ac, string me)
{
    vm.AdminDetails = _link.Detail(ac + me).ToList();

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView(vm);
    return View(vm);
}
```

Without the `return PartialView(vm);` the HTML response for the AJAX request would include your pages header