# Problems implementing Ajax to return a HTML.Partial page in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement an Ajax way to update my data grid. So far I have coded the following in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string ac, string me) {     
   vm.AdminDetails = _link.Detail(ac + me).ToList();      
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())         
      return PartialView(vm);     
   return View(vm); 
}
```

My snapshot of the view looks like this:

```
@model ViewModels.Shared.BaseViewModel
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administration/Views/Menus/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section content {
<div class="bdy_box">
        <div id="detailData" class="rep_tb0">
        // code to generate the list of data
        </div>
</div>
```

My snapshot of the javascript looks like this:

```
function reload(entity, pk) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Administration/" + entity + "s/Detail",
        data: { pk: pk },
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function (responseText) {
            $('#detailData').html(responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

The data does get returned BUT my problem is other data also gets returned. When I look at the contents of the detailData div I see much more than I need. For example I see something like the following:

```
<div class="rep_tb0" id="detailData">  
<title></title>    
<meta content="" name="title">    
<meta content="" name="description">     
<meta content="" name="keywords">    
<link type="image/x-icon" href="/Content/Favicons/default.ico" rel="shortcut icon">     
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Stylesheets/Style203.css">
```

Is there a reason why it's showing me all this and how can I stop it showing all this header type of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melissa,

I'm assuming that you have a partialview called `_detail.cshtml` (if not, you need to create one)??

I believe that you may be actually invoking the 'full' view detail.cshtml based on your sample. I'd suggest that you call your action it along the following lines:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string ac, string me) {     
   vm.AdminDetails = _link.Detail(ac + me).ToList();      
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())         
      return PartialView("_details", vm);     
   return View(vm); 
}
```

Comment: No partial view. This is Ajax data going back to the javascript.

Comment: Melissa, you're gonna need to have a partial view for this to work, otherwise, your div is always going to get populated with the contents of the full view. create a partialview with the required 'partial' elements and you'll be good to go. (also, amend your action as per my reply above)

Comment: Jim. Going by what StanK says in this post I don't believe he is saying I need a partial view. Maybe I'm just reading it wrong but seems like he is saying it will be okay and makes no mention of another view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782879/how-can-i-code-a-refresh-of-a-html-renderpartial-using-ajax-in-mvc3/8782887#comment10958218_8782887

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your request is made with `X-Requested-With` HTTP Header being set. Check that with developer tools addon to your browser (in Chrome and IE9 it's built in, in Firefox get Firebug). You may want to double check your code under different browsers as there were different unexplained issues occuring in the past with IsAjaxRequest (possibly dependant on browser settings )