# MVC How To Update A Page Following A Variable Change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an ASP.Net MVC website and each page contains a lot of partial views, in various combinations.

I get the values for the Partial Views from a model in a dll and then bind values from the dll  to the partial views. That is working fine.

Some of my Partial Views contain input controls which should drive changes in the model on the dll. Therefore after changes in one or more inputs I need to refresh the page with the new values from the dll.

So, its a bit of a general question but what is the best way for getting the new values from the dll and giving them to the partial views? Is there a general strategy for this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I guess you are looking for nothing but AJAX.

Comment: To get a quality answer, you are going to need to be more specific, and add some code we can have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses. I used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787041/whats-the-most-mvc-standard-way-to-refresh-update-part-of-an-mvc-page). I think her question is phrased far better than mine which is probably why she got an answer.