# 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' does not contain a definition for 'JavaScriptStringEncode'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view I am trying to reload a Html.Action via JQuery.

I'm using a method from this SO >[How can I code a refresh of a HTML.RenderPartial using Ajax in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782879/how-can-i-code-a-refresh-of-a-html-renderpartial-using-ajax-in-mvc3)

When I run the code I get an exception:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' does not contain a definition for 'JavaScriptStringEncode' and no extension method 'JavaScriptStringEncode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
$('#checkoutProgress').load("@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("CheckoutProgress", new {step = CheckoutProgressStep.Address}))");
```

Comment: I assume you want `UrlEncode` (not `JavaScriptStringEncode`) although its not clear why you need to use that (instead of just `"Url.Action(...)"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Stephen. It's meant to reload the html from the partial view.  btw I think you helped me a while back with API method calls in C# if I'm not mistaken.. :) cool stuff. small world.

Comment: Yes I know, but why do you think you need `JavaScriptStringEncode`?

Comment: I'm following the example from the SO Q in my question..I'm not 100% sure. I thought this would be the way it would reload the partial view. I'm still testing and it's not reloading it though ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*facepalm

Hope this can help anyways.

I found that I was using the incorrect namespace :/

Here is the correct namespace:

```
$('#checkoutProgress').load("@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("CheckoutProgress", new {step = CheckoutProgressStep.Address}))");
```

Comment: My own answer did not work. At least I got passed the error. But partial view still not reloading.